# Que significa el char **argv?

Tags: c

Hola estuve programando en C y vi un ejemplo donde usaban `char **argv[]` que significa?, se que el `char *argv[]` (con un solo puntero) significa el arreglo que entra en los comandos de
ejecucion, pero que pasa cuando es doble puntero?

gracias

Comment: `char **argv[]` es incorrecto, si se usa como segundo parámetro de `main` el compilador debería rechazar el código.

Comment: A lo mejor lo que viste fue `char **argv`, sin los corchetes. Eso es una sintaxis equivalente a `char *argv[]` (con los corchetes pero un solo asterisco)